# How can I push the content on the right to the bottom with Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie to Bootstrap 4, and I've created a new version of my acronym website. Things look good on my PC (resizing Firefox works well), it looks good on my iPad, but it looks bad on my iPhone 6.

For instance on, http://www.abkuerzung.ch/index2.php the content on the right is shown, even though it doesn't have the space, and the background color is shown only partially.

When delivering the results of a search, for instance http://www.abkuerzung.ch/search2.php?abk=ht* the content doesn't have enough space and doesn't wrap.

Basically I'm doing the following:

```
<div class="col-10">
...
</div>
<div class="col-2">
...
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: `col-*` are the non-stacking (xs) columns. Use a responsive breakpoint like `col-sm-*` instead.

Comment: @ZimSystem : Thanks a lot, I changed the classes, and almost everything looks perfect. However, some pages like the search result http://www.abkuerzung.ch/search2.php?abk=ht* or http://www.abkuerzung.ch/latest2.php are rendered too wide for my iPhone in portrait mode. Is this because the text is in a table?